# Accordion plus-minus icons on open/close - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Changing icons on open/close accordion states.

Template:

```
<div v-b-toggle.accordion1 class="accordion-header" @click="isActive = !isActive">
  <h4>Quesstion?</h4>
  <i class="fas" :class="{ 'fa-plus': !isActive, 'fa-minus': isActive }"></i>
</div>
```

Data:

```
data () {
 return {
   isActive: false
 }
}
```

It does work, when i click on accordion header, my icon changes from plus to minus, but if i have more that one question, they all will be changing plus to minus, and vice versa, because they're sharing the same data `isActive`. How to separate each element, so only clicked item would have icons changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create separate state for your `questions` I would simply make a component out of your question. This way every question has its own state.

Of course that leads to the problem of every component having the same template, so you can make a component slot to pass in the unique content for each question. Optionally you can pass the unique content into a `question` component with props if the data is small enough.